# uitable with subcolumn headers in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-uitable

I want to create a uitable with three main columns. The second one should have two subcolumns and the third one three.

```
cnames= {'Material','Rand| Left Right','Snitt| p1 p2 p3'} ;
data={'Iron' '2'  ' ' '34' '' ''};
uitable('columnname',cnames,...
    'position',[300 0300 300 0200],...
    'data',data);
```

I want the material column to contron Iron, the first subcolumn of  Rand should be 2 and the second blank, and so on.

Is there a good way to do this or do I have to use textboxes above the uitable?

Answer (score 0):

With just the built-in Matlab tools, there is no good way to do what you're trying to do. There is a similar question that may or may not be of use to you here: [Multiple Column Header On Uitable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/332906). Even though it wouldn't be very clean, adding a text box or even just another table above that table could work as well but I know that's what you were trying to avoid in the first place :P

Comment: Didn't think of multiple tables! I guess you can make it look kinda good with some effort...